# Using a VMWare installation as a development webserver

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webserver, vmware

Can anyone point me into the right direction to use a VMWare installation of Ubuntu or another  Linux distro as a development server on my local machine?

I'm on a Windows 7 32bit machine and currently using WAMP.

I'm noticing some differences between developing on a windows machine and my deployment server and additionaly I'd like to expand my knowledge on working on linux using the command line.

Follow-up question, what would be the best way to develop on my local installation and push that development to my VPS that I'm renting?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggesting downloading a LAMP appliance from http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/cat/0?k=lamp if you don't want to get into building your own, and running that on VMWare Player.

If you want to build your own, you could use VMWare Server, Oracle VirtualBox or any other Virtualization software. Create a New VM, with 512MB or RAM, and 4GB (+ the requirements of your tools + a buffer of 2GB) of disk. I recommend 10GB, or you could set it up for maybe 50GB and let the virtual disk grow as needed rather than allocating all the space up front.

Then, download the Ubuntu Server 12.04 ISO file from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server , and use it as the CD Drive to boot your VM. Follow the on-screen instructions to install. And at the end, select the options to install the LAMP configuration.

Note: Using Ubuntu's server edition means you don't get any GUI.

Comment: I understand the process of installing a virtual OS using VMWare but how can I connect to that server on my local physical OS? So I'd like to keep developing on my windows 7 machine but use the LAMP installation on VMware as my "remote server". Can I just connect to the virtual IP?

Comment: Depends on the how you setup networking for the VM. If you use the bridged adapter, you can just SSH to the ip address of the VM. If you're using NAT instead, setup port-forwarding. Tie port 22 of the guest to port 2222 (or 22 if it's unused on your Win machine) of the host, and SSH to localhost:2222 (or localhost:22).